# iframe source problem with Safari

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem with Safari

Whenever the source of the iframe changes the new source is not displayed it instead shown as a download file.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<?php echo "<iframe id='myframe' width='600' height='200' src='image3.php?id=$content'  style='margin-left:25; background-color:#ffffff'></iframe>";?>
```

and in JS:

```
function refreshConsole() {
var url = "image3.php?id=<?php echo $content; ?>";

document.getElementById("myframe").src=url;
setInterval("refreshConsole()", 15000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
refreshConsole();
});
```

It works fine with FireFox and Chrome but not in Safari.Is the problem with code or with the browser

Editted:

Here is image3 file

```
<?php
require("db.php");
db_connect();
$id=addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
$image3=mysql_query("select * from image where id=$id");
$image2=mysql_fetch_array($image3);
$content2=$image2['image'];
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $content2;
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you navigate to that page outside of an iframe? How are the http headers set on image3.php?

Answer (score 1):

What about to use this directly in iframE?

like

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.location.reload();
}, 15000);
```

Comment: how can I use this one inside iframe can u please give me an example.

Comment: <script>setTimeout(function(){
   document.location.reload();
}, 15000);</script>

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. The image still opened as a download file not as an image

Comment: @Amal: you do have binary image in your database ? BTW you should read something about SQLi

Comment: yes the image is in BLOB type that's why i used image3.php to render this kind of images